# Strange issue with TomEE 8.0.4 and OpenApi extension (Swagger-UI 1.0.3)

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, apache-tomee, microprofile

I'm using TomEE microprofile and have defined my rest application path this way:

```
 @ApplicationPath("api")
 public class RestConfiguration extends Application {

 }
```

When the application is deployed, tomee log shows the access url to the generated front end resources:

```
 Service URI: http://localhost:8080/api/openapi-ui/
```

When accesing the url got this message in the swagger-ui web page:

> Fetch error undefined /openapi

If I change the application path to empty:

```
 @ApplicationPath("")
```

Then all works fine and swagger shows all of the service method definitions.

So, what should I do to make it work adding "api" to the ApplicationPath annotation?

Tried with "/api", but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the test here with Tomee-8.0.4, follow the configurations, assumed that you that is using a JAR.

in your pom.xml use the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.microprofile-ext.openapi-ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

 <build>
        <finalName>tomee-demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tomee.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>executable-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <context>ROOT</context>
                    <tomeeClassifier>microprofile</tomeeClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

in **microprofile-config.properties** use:

```
mp.openapi.servers=http://localhost:8080/api
openapi.ui.yamlUrl=/api/openapi
openapi.ui.serverVisibility=visible
```

and run your project again.

[test performed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzsoT.png)

reference:
https://github.com/microprofile-extensions/openapi-ext/tree/master/openapi-ui

Comment: After following your suggestions about the microprofile-config.properties file, the issue was solved and now the swagger ui it's working fine. Thanks for that info man!.